# ORA-00911 error in oracle

Tags: oracle

```
                   DELETE FROM R1_;
                        DELETE FROM C1;
                        DELETE FROM R1;     

                        INSERT INTO R1_(ID,PRODUCTID1)
                        SELECT A.SIPARISHEADER_ID,A.PRODUCTID FROM TBLSIPARIS A
                        GROUP BY A.PRODUCTID,A.SIPARISHEADER_ID 
                        ORDER BY PRODUCTID;

                        INSERT INTO C1(PRODUCTID1,SUPPORT )
                        SELECT A.PRODUCTID1,COUNT(*)  FROM R1_ A
                        GROUP BY A.PRODUCTID1
                        HAVING COUNT(*)>2;

                        INSERT INTO R1(ID,PRODUCTID1)
                        SELECT A.ID,A.PRODUCTID1 FROM R1_ A, C1 B
                        WHERE A.PRODUCTID1 = B.PRODUCTID1;

                        SELECT A.PRODUCTID1,B.PRODUCTNAME PRODUCTNAME1,A.SUPPORT FROM C1 A
                        JOIN TBLPRODUCTS B ON (A.PRODUCTID1 = B.PRODUCTID);
```

Comment: The second `INSERT INTO` yields the question: What (and how many) fields does the `C1` table have? Two or more?

Comment: The error code is . ORA-00911

Comment: error text is invalid character. there's still error.

Comment: OK. This going to sound weird but try by getting rid of the last semicolon. ( `;` )

Comment: How and where are you executing this? Which one of the 7 statements throws the error, and what other details (line, position) are given?  - or is it coming from your client not liking multiple statements separated by semicolons? You could try using a `/` on the next line instead of each semicolon but that' guesswork at this point.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend:

1. Get into SQL*Plus
2. Copy and paste each statement and execute, one by one.
3. Report back the statement that exhibits the error